# unexpected code 404 on publishing react native app on expo

Tags: ios, react-native, publishing, expo

I have been trying to publish my react-native app on expo so I can show it to others.
But i am facing error. I looked up on internet but couldn't find solution that can solve my problem.
The error is:

Building iOS bundle
Packager URL http://127.0.0.1:80/index.bundle?dev=false&minify=true&hot=false&platform=ios returned unexpected code 404. Please open your project in the Expo app and see if there are any errors. Also scroll up and make sure there were no errors or warnings when opening your project.

I am using visual studio code and when i run app by

> expo start

It opens.. shows QR code... I scan with my iphone..and app opens in expo client.. works perfectly fine there but the above error comes when i try to publish.

can anyone tell me what might be the issue here please ?

Answer (score 2):

Try to publish the app again unchecking the 'Optimize Assets' checkbox. This works for me.

Comment: It's better to use comments for trying stuff instead of answers.